# App Engine Blob Store URL Response in Production Differs From Development

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am using Go SDK (`1.9.34 - 2016-03-15`) on App Engine. The blobstore api was working correctly in both dev and production but now it seems to return different results, which now breaks the upload.

When I use this code in dev (using `goapp serve`) and production I get different results. The `GET` request comes with a parameter, which I extract and add it to the upload URL.

```
c          := appengine.NewContext(r)
upUrl, err := blobstore.UploadURL(c, "/upload", nil)
c.Infof("Upload url = %+v", upUrl)

if (err != nil) { //error handling here }

param      := r.FormValue("param")
q          := upUrl.Query()
q.Set("param", param)
upUrl.RawQuery = q.Encode()
c.Infof("Upload url after query  = %+v", upUrl)
```

In `Dev` I get (this is the intended behavior):

```
Upload url = http://localhost:8080/_ah/upload/RANDOMSTRING
Upload url after query = http://localhost:8080/_ah/upload/RANDOMSTRING?param=99
```

In `Prod` I get (incorrect upload url is being constructed):

```
Upload url = https://www.example.com/_ah/upload/?param=99/RANDOMSTRING1/RANDOMSTRING2/
Upload url after query = https://www.example.com/_ah/upload/?param=99
```

I know it is recommended to use Cloud Storage instead of blobstore but this is a legacy code so I don't want to change it right now. It was working fine a couple of weeks back and just noticed a difference. I upgrade from an older SDK to newer one (the results are based on the latest SDK) but still made no difference.

Any suggestions on what could be going wrong?

Thanks!